# When creating a char array, its length is different from required

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I need to create a `newStr` array with length of `str` array. But after its created the `strlen(newStr)` is totally different. For example if a `strlen(str)` is 5, then `strlen(newStr)` would be 22. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *str = "Hello";
    int strLength = strlen(str);
    std::cout << "str = " << str << "\t" << "strLength = " << strLength << std::endl;
    char *newStr = new char[strLength];
    std::cout << "newStrLength = " << strlen(newStr) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In the console will be

```
str = Hello     strLength = 5
newStrLength = 22
```

Comment: The content of the second "string" is uninitialised.

Comment: Because `strlen` doesn't look at the size of the allocated space, it returns the size of the string in that allocated space by looking for the trailing `\0` at the end of the string. You haven't put anything into it though, so it's just looking at garbage memory and returning a garbage result. Hard to say for sure but you probably want to look into `strcpy`.

Comment: Anyway, you'd need to allocate `strlen(source) + 1` because presumably `newStr` will also need its own `\0` terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two different concepts:

- `new[]` allocates uninitialized memory block to your program,
- `strlen(...)` counts characters in a C string before null terminator `'\0'` is reached.

The size of the allocated block cannot be measured with `strlen`. In fact, it cannot be measured at all - your program must know how much memory it has requested, and make sure that it does not go past the limit.

Once you allocated `new char[n]`, you can safely copy a C string of length up to `n-1` into that block. C++ guarantees that enough memory would be there for you to complete the operation successfully:

```
char *newStr = new char[strLength+1]; // Note +1 for null terminator
strcpy(newStr, str);
std::cout << "newStrLength = " << strlen(newStr) << std::endl;
delete[] newStr;
```

Comment: So, is it right that after initialization of memory by doing  a new[] the newStr is fulled of junk, thats why after strlen(newStr) its returns different numbers?

Comment: @Nikita.L That's right. Whatever comes back from `new char[...]` is junk. For non-primitive data types the constructor would be called, so you'd get some meaningful objects. For primitives the memory is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

The way strlen works is that it examines the contents of the string passed to it, and counts how many characters there are until the first terminating character.  The terminating character for a string is '\0' (or 0).

What you've done is asked for the length of a string that you've not assigned any value to; leading to strlen examining random memory; looking for the first 0.  In this case, it found it 22 bytes further down; but it could be anything.  It could even crash because you start looking into memory you don't have read access to.

The best way to resolve this is to use std::string and then you can call length and other helper functions without having to worry about the underlying pointers too much; which will also resolve your memory leak.

Comment: Thank for answer, now I see. The funny thing is that i`m not allowed to use std::string.

Comment: @Nikita.L In that case I would strongly suggest creating your own version.